# Order by multiple columns, ignoring Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-order-by, sql-server-2016

I have a view, which shows the time when a certain item has arrived at multiple locations. I want to order this view according to arrival time:

```
ITEM | At Loc1 | At Loc2 | At Loc3 | At Loc4 | Desired Order
--------------------------------------------------------
aaa  | 00:00   | 02:01   | NULL    | 05:30   | 0
bbb  | NULL    | 02:30   | 06:21   | NULL    | 1
ccc  | 00:05   | 02:33   | NULL    | 07:10   | 2 
ddd  | 00:07   | NULL    | 06:25   | 09:00   | 3
eee  | NULL    | NULL    | 06:30   | 09:10   | 4
fff  | 00:30   | 02:55   | 06:32   | NULL    | 5
```

Sometimes the time of arrival is not recored, due to a measurement error or irregularity. In that case the time is `NULL`

Now I want to `Select * from View ORDER BY AtLoc1 ASC, AtLoc2 ASC, AtLoc3 ASC, AtLoc4 ASC`

But Null values in a column should not cause the item to go to the front or the back. It should stay in the correct relative position according to the next column.

For example, item bbb has not been recorded at location 1, but it arrived at location 2 after aaa and before ccc, so it should be sorted between aaa and ccc, not at the start or end of the list

In most cases items do not change their order between locations, but it is not impossible.

I don't think I can define a sort order that is unique and well-defined for all special cases, When there are too many NULLs clustered together, then the order may be undefined. But I just want to cover the most common cases where null values are relatively sparse.

How can I order the view in SQL in this way?

Comment: Hmm, PIVOT then ORDER BY then UNPIVOT? That's a tricky one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more testing, but try this one:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/XGUCN11108)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN [At Loc1] IS NOT NULL 
                THEN row_number() over (order by  [At Loc1] ) 
           END as r1,
           CASE WHEN [At Loc2] IS NOT NULL 
                THEN row_number() over (order by  [At Loc2] ) 
           END as r2,
           CASE WHEN [At Loc3] IS NOT NULL 
                THEN row_number() over (order by  [At Loc3] ) 
           END as r3,
           CASE WHEN [At Loc4] IS NOT NULL 
                THEN row_number() over (order by  [At Loc4] ) 
           END as r4
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT *, COALESCE(r1,r2,r3,r4)
FROM cte
ORDER BY COALESCE(r1,r2,r3,r4),
         COALESCE(r2,r3,r4),
         COALESCE(r3,r4),
         r4
;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot get a stable sort, because you could have something like this:

```
aaa     1      7
bbb  NULL      6
ccc     2      5
```

Basically, these three things are true:

- ccc > aaa
- bbb > ccc
- aaa > bbb

These cannot all be true at the same time (at least not for numbers -- or times -- as we usually use them).

Juan Carlos gives a very good ad-hoc solution, but it will not work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I knew there were to many cases and I couldn't test it all. To make thing clear and for reference this is the result of my query using Gordon data http://rextester.com/ULYBQ46358